# Which individuals does Ramban say do not enjoy providential treatment by G-d?

Tags: ekev, ramban, hashgacha-pratit

[Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.13?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) on [Deuteronomy 11:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0511.htm#13):

> ""**בכל לבבכם ובכל נפשכם**" - והלא כבר הזכיר בכל לבבך ובכל נפשך אלא אזהרה ליחיד ואזהרה לצבור לשון רש"י מספרי (עקב יג). ובאור הענין כי השם לא יעשה הנסים תמיד לתת מטר הארץ בכל עת יורה ומלקוש ולהוסיף בדגן ובתירוש וביצהר ולהרבות גם העשב בשדה לבהמה או שיעצור השמים וייבשו **רק על מעשה רוב העם אבל היחיד הוא בזכותו יחיה והוא בעונו ימות** והנה אמר כי בעשותם כל המצות מאהבה שלימה יעשה עמהם את כל הנסים האלה לטובה ואמר כי בעבדם ע"ז יעשה עמהם אות לרעה **ודע כי הנסים לא יעשו לטובה או לרעה רק לצדיקים גמורים או לרשעים גמורים אבל הבינונים כדרך מנהגו של עולם יעשה בהם טובה או רעה כדרכם וכעלילותם**"

Thus, whereas the fate of the Jews as a nation is guided by providence, individuals do not enjoy the same providential relationship with the Almighty. Only the righteous and the wicked can expect providential treatment. The fate of more “average” individuals is primarily guided by the laws of nature.

Who are those "average" individuals?

Comment: The Ramban on [Job 36:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39727&st=&pgnum=198) says that God watches humans more than animals, and righteous people more than ordinary people. I don't see how his comments on these two passages fit together, though, and they even seem to contradict each other

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73235/9215  may help

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The Ramban you quote clearly says anybody not part of צדיקים גמורים או לרשעים גמורים  do not qualify.

Comment: See [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1453522?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) article.

Comment: It does not seem like the Rambam says that anyone does not enjoy providential treatment. He says that most people do not have MIRACLES done for them unless they are absolute Tzadikim or MIRACLES done against them if they are absolute Resoyim but everyone has providence guiding him in non miraculous areas