What is Ramban's true opinion regarding the scope of hashgachah pratis?
Ramban seemingly contradicts himself regarding this subject.
In Bereishis 18:19 (and Iyov 36:7) he says explicitly that only the righteous are under total divine protection; others, which comprise the majority of people, are left to the vagaries of nature.

ירמוז כי ידיעת השם שהיא השגחתו בעולם השפל היא לשמור הכללים, וגם בני האדם מונחים בו למקרים עד בא עת פקודתם, אבל בחסידיו ישים אליו לבו לדעת אותו בפרט, להיות שמירתו דבוקה בו תמיד, לא תפרד הידיעה והזכירה ממנו כלל, כטעם: לא יגרע מצדיק עינו (איוב ל"ו:ז'). ובאו מזה פסוקים רבים, כדכתיב: הנה עין י"י אל יראיו (תהלים ל"ג:י"ח) וזולת זה.
He is thus alluding that G-d's knowledge, which is synonymous with His Providence in the lower world, is to guard the species, and even the children of men are subject despite it to the circumstantial evil occurrences until the time of their visitation comes. But as regards His pious, He directs His Providence to know each one individually so that His watch constantly attaches to him, His knowledge and remembrance of him never departs, as it says: He withdraweth not His eyes from the righteous.⁠ There are many verses on this theme, as it is written, Behold, the eye of the Eternal is toward them that fear Him,⁠ and other verses besides.

Whereas in Shemos 13:16 Ramban is quite forceful that nature is merely a smokescreen for the total divine micromanagement of everyone.

ומן הנסים הגדולים המפורסמים, אדם מודה בנסים הנסתרים שהם יסוד התורה כלה, שאין לאדם חלק בתורת משה רבינו עד שיאמין שכל דברינו ומקרינו כולם נסים אין בהם טבע ומנהגו של עולם, בין ברבים בין ביחיד, אלא אם יעשה המצות יצליחנו שכרו, ואם יעבר עליהן יכריתנו עונשו הגדול בגזרת עליון כאשר הזכרתי כבר
Through the great open miracles, one comes to admit the hidden miracles which constitute the foundation of the whole Torah, for no one can have a part in the Torah of Moses our teacher unless he believes that all our words and our events, [as dictated in the Torah], are miraculous in scope, there being no natural or customary way of the world in them, whether affecting the public or the individual. Instead, if a person observes the commandments, His reward will bring him success, and if he violates them, His punishment will cause his extinction. It is all by decree of the Most High, as I have already mentioned.

How to reconcile?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73235/6592

The second reference itself says ויעשו אדם כדגי הים שלא ישגיח הא-ל בהם, implying that there are tiers of hashgacha.

@shmosel Ramban certainly holds that non human animate matter is only subject to hashgachah klalis. He is making the point that some make the same assertion (wrongly) regarding humans as well.

So your question is whether it applies to all humans or only some individuals?

@shmosel Yupper

See R Dr David Berger's (no relation) article "Miracles and the Natural Order in Nahmanides": https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781618117915-005/html Basically, RDB argues that if you look at each quote in context, when the Rambam denies the existence of nature, he is talking about reward and punishment, and in the other contexts, he is talking about Providence in general. See also https://www.torahmusings.com/2005/02/r-moshe-shternbuchs-position/
